# Low Search for location/proximity searches

Tags: search, low-search, google-maps-for-ee

Is it possible to use Low Search for creating a store finder kind of search?

I'm currently using Channel Search in combination with Google Maps for ExpressionEngine and while it's pretty good the search system also uses a large number of categories. I'm seeing some performance problems because of this.

I've recently used Low Search on another site to search through and filter a large number of categories and I've been really impressed by its speed.

So what I'm hoping I can do is combine Low Search with Google Maps for ExpressionEngine to get a fast search system which allows the user to search for properties within a radius of a specified location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low Search's [Distance filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#distance) requires that lat/long values are stored in **two separate channel fields**. Also, you need to feed it lat/long values yourself; it won't take data like a post code as a starting location.

If these conditions are met, you can use the Distance filter to filter entries by distance/proximity. If not, then you'd need a custom filter or extension to allow for it.

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't even know about the distance filter. I best go and read the docs again! Thanks!